# Discord.py how to send a specific leave message when a user is banned instead of regular leave message

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a basic leave message set up already in a cog. How could I go about sending a different message depending on whether the user was banned/kicked or left voluntarily?

I've looked around as much as I can, and since the *on_member_remove* event only offers the *Member* object, I can't figure out how to do this without using audit logs which are extremely unreliable.

I tried figuring out a variable when my bot banned a member to check, but I couldn't find a reasonable way to do that, and it obviously wouldn't function when a member was banned manually by a staff member.

Here's the basic leave listener:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_remove(self, member):
    chan = self.bot.get_channel(805991434330570793)
    await chan.send(f"{member.display_name}#{member.tag} just left the server.")
```

And it along with some pseudo describing what I want:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_remove(self, member):
    chan = self.bot.get_channel(805991434330570793)
    methods = ["banned", "kicked"]
    if member.leave_method in methods:
        await chan.send(f"{member.display_name}#{member.tag} was just banned from the server.")
    else:
        await chan.send(f"{member.display_name}#{member.tag} just left the server.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bot has the `ban_members` permission, you could use [`guild.fetch_ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_ban) to check if the member is banned, otherwise it will throw [`discord.NotFound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.NotFound):

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_remove(self, member):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(805991434330570793)
    try:
        banned = await member.guild.fetch_ban(member)
    except discord.NotFound:
        banned = False
    if banned:
        await channel.send(f"{member} was just banned from the server.")
    else:
        await channel.send(f"{member} just left the server.")
```

There is also a separate listener for only bans, [`on_member_ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_ban), that requires `Intents.bans` to be enabled. For kicks, checking the audit logs would be the only method that I am aware of, though it might be somewhat unreliable as you mentioned.

Comment: Oh thank you! I guess that goes to show that I should always read the docs carefully!